# create new object with params from other object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have in my controller a action with **@post = Post.new**

and in my view the next form:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :method => :get, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "posts", :action => "new_posts_from_web" }) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :remote_posted_url%>
<%= f.submit "Find Images" %>
```

I want create in action **new_posts_from_web** a new post with params sent by the previous form, and I have this in new_posts_from_web action:

```
def new_posts_from_web
 @post = Post.new(params[:id])
end
```

but I get a new post without params.

How can I get params from a form in other action without save in database the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
```

should work fine.